# Tabular Model - Sort by column: Property value is not valid multiple distinct values

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

I have the following date table:

[image]

When I use the MonthYear Past column and want to sort, the sort order is alphabetically instead of chronical. When I want to change to Sort Order in SSAS tabular model, I choose datekey or date but get the following error:

```
Property value is not valid 
Cannot sort MonthYear Past by Date because at least one value in 
MonthYear Past has multiple distinct values in Date. For example,
you can sort [City] by [Region] because there is only one region for each city,
but you cannot sort [Region] by [City] because there are multiple cities for each region.
```

How can I sort this column chronical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this:

Because Past is linked with multiple values, I created a new calculated column where when it is past the value is 1, else the value is YearMonth. & then sort order on your new calculated column